# bar alignment issue in d3 js w.r.t Safari

Tags: d3.js

I have tick to bar alignment issues in safari however the issues does not happen for firefox and chrome
js fiddle for this is jsfiddle.net/reddy555/WhAUZ/13/

Please check this in safari to observe ticks to bar misalignment.

Comment: Offset by `barHeight` -- http://jsfiddle.net/WhAUZ/14/

Comment: well that causes misalignment in chrome

Comment: You may find [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/) helpful.

Comment: What exactly is the difference we are looking for? The chart looks the same in all 3 browsers for me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yo5hrovthpnlajl/Screenshot%202014-06-14%2012.55.36.jpg